# I have to use "IN Operator" but can't use"True" in the codes to get "True" as an answer

Tags: python, string

I had to modify the code in such a way that I use "In operator" and the result should display "True" if a given word is found in string

```
mystery_string = "Hello, world!"
```

```
#You may modify the lines of code above, but don't move them!
#When you Submit your code, we'll change these lines to
#assign different values to the variables.

#The 'in' operator can be used to see if a string of characters
#is found within another string of characters, just like it can
#be used to find if an item is in a list.

#Above we've created a string with the variable name
#mystery_string. Write some code below that will print True
#if the string "world" appears within mystery_string, and
#False if it does not.


#Write your code here!
```

```
if "world" in mystery_string:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

```
#dropdown in the top left:
#We found the str "True" declared in your code. You shouldn't be creating this value 
 #manually.`
```

Comment: What does the `in` operator return?

Comment: What is _your_ question?

Comment: How about ```print("world" in mystery_string)```. This will just print either ```True``` or ```False``` and you're not using them anywhere in code.

Answer (score 0):

`"world" in mystery_string` returns a boolean value. You should not have to print True or false manually. Instead, you can do `print("world" in mystery_string)`. This should print true if world is in string else print false.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("world" in mystery_string)
```

Finally, it worked!